# How to set a minimum width for MudBlazor MudDataGrid columns?

Tags: c#, html, datagrid, asp.net-blazor, mudblazor

I need to set a minimum width for the some of the columns in my `MudBlazor MudDataGrid`.

I could not find an option in the MudDataGrid column component and even when I set a minimum width in the `CSS` style property of the column component there was no change to the width.

How do I go about setting a minimum width for the MudDataGrid columns that need it?

```
<MudDataGrid T="Car" Items="@Cars" Sortable="true" Filterable="false" Outlined="true">
    <Columns>
        <Column T="Car" Field="Description" Sortable="false" Title="Description" Style="min-width: 1000px"/> 
    </Columns>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudDataGridPager T="Car" />
    </PagerContent>
</MudDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the `CellStyle` parameter of the `Column`.

```html
<Column CellStyle="min-width: 1000px;" T="Car" Field="Description" Sortable="false" Title="Description" />
```

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QEmxOlYHCztUtxRO